# How can I update known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh

I use `git fetch` to get new code. but it shows these woring message:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (198.18.0.74)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
hostfile_replace_entries: mkstemp: No such file or directory
update_known_hosts: hostfile_replace_entries failed for /c/Users/aecra/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I did some things to my computer, but I can't remember what I did.

I have this in my file `config` in folder `.ssh` and I have file `git_github` as my secret key.

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_github
```

I tried to add some thing to file `known_hosts`, but it didn't work.

When I use `ssh` to connect to my remote vps, it shows the same message.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog entry](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) from github has notes on removing old keys and adding new keys.